# how to separate one DataFrame into two small ones

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big `DataFrame` as below:

```
            count   mean  median    min    max   std
datet                                               
2001-05-16     17    NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
2001-05-17     24   8.28    8.27   8.15   8.46  0.09
2001-05-18     24   8.41    8.31   8.18   8.85  0.19
2001-05-19     24  10.44   10.64   9.03  10.98  0.60
2001-05-20     24  10.53   10.56   9.98  10.92  0.28
2001-05-21     24  10.28   10.31   9.90  10.66  0.23
2001-05-22     24  10.40   10.42  10.17  10.67  0.17
2001-05-23     24  10.04   10.03   9.87  10.17  0.08
2001-05-24     24   9.63    9.66   9.41   9.88  0.15
2001-05-25     24   9.21    9.22   9.01   9.41  0.11
```

how can I separate this `DataFrame` into two small ones according to before or after date '2001-05-20'? like below:

```
df1:
         count   mean  median    min    max   std
datet                                               
2001-05-16     17    NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
2001-05-17     24   8.28    8.27   8.15   8.46  0.09
2001-05-18     24   8.41    8.31   8.18   8.85  0.19
2001-05-19     24  10.44   10.64   9.03  10.98  0.60
2001-05-20     24  10.53   10.56   9.98  10.92  0.28

df2:
     count   mean  median    min    max   std
datet                                               
2001-05-21     24  10.28   10.31   9.90  10.66  0.23
2001-05-22     24  10.40   10.42  10.17  10.67  0.17
2001-05-23     24  10.04   10.03   9.87  10.17  0.08
2001-05-24     24   9.63    9.66   9.41   9.88  0.15
2001-05-25     24   9.21    9.22   9.01   9.41  0.11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single before/after split, I think grouping by a boolean criterion is the most direct approach.

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10),
                       index=pd.date_range('2001-05-16', '2001-05-25'))

In [2]: grouper = df.groupby(df.index < pd.Timestamp('2001-05-21'))

In [3]: before, after = grouper.get_group(True), grouper.get_group(False)

In [4]: before
Out[4]: 
               0
2001-05-16  2.560516
2001-05-17 -2.207314
2001-05-18  0.646882
2001-05-19  0.660611
2001-05-20  0.437303
```

And `after` comes out right as well. Can anyone improve on my `In [3]`?

Answer (score 3):

0.11-dev (.ix will work equivalently)

```
In [16]: df.loc[:'20010520']
Out[16]: 
                   0
2001-05-16  0.105445
2001-05-17  1.660771
2001-05-18  0.485668
2001-05-19 -0.102616
2001-05-20 -0.228228

In [17]: df.loc['20010521':]
Out[17]: 
                   0
2001-05-21 -0.024324
2001-05-22 -1.004362
2001-05-23  2.342225
2001-05-24  1.124695
2001-05-25 -0.291302
```

or (ix will work here as well, this is just more explicit)

```
 In [27]: i = df.index.get_loc('20010520')

In [28]: df.iloc[:i+1]
Out[28]: 
                   0
2001-05-16  0.105445
2001-05-17  1.660771
2001-05-18  0.485668
2001-05-19 -0.102616
2001-05-20 -0.228228

In [29]: df.iloc[i+1:]
Out[29]: 
                   0
2001-05-21 -0.024324
2001-05-22 -1.004362
2001-05-23  2.342225
2001-05-24  1.124695
2001-05-25 -0.291302
```